# How to default a content type's Language field to the authenticated user's language?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, multi-sites

We are using Entity Translation so that content can be created in several language. One item we noticed is that on the basic page, for example, has a language field that you can set when you create a piece of content. As of right now, any users regardless of if their profile's preferred language is set to French (for example), the French user is still able to create a content in English.

Ideal scenario:

If a French user logs in and creates content of type basic page, then the language field should be set to French. If a German user logs in and performs the same actions, the language should be restricted to just creating content using the German language.

Any thoughts on how I would set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, i would create a custom module (i hope, you know how to code a bit)

the code should be something like the following:

```
    <?php
    function YOUR_CUSTOM_MODULE_node_presave($node){
        global $user; // gets the current user account
        $node->language=$user->language;
    }
```